# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was
>   implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error:

This exception occured after 7 hrs with out using connection.

what is good solution for this problem

Comment: Please have a look on this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908953/how-to-fix-com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception

Comment: Use a connection pool that restricts the maximum lifetime of a database connection. Get connection from pool when needed, and close it (which returns it to the pool) as soon as your unit of work is done.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is happend because jar version and mysql version are not matching.
I encountered the same error when i am having mysql-connector-java-5.1.25 to connect mysql verion 8.